# SonarQube plugin install for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have successfully install the SonarQube plugin for Jenkins. I am following this article which says click on "advance button" under SonarQube configuration. But I don't see the advance button there which I have to config the sonar server details.

When I go to Plugin manager-Installed, I can see the SonarQube 2.2.1 Plugin also.

[Reference](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Configuring+Jenkins+SonarQube+Plugin).

[image: SonarQube Runner Section in Jenkins Configuration]

Edit:

Q1) When i ran the sonar build i get below error, but the sonar build get success. I can see the dashboard was populated but i am uncertain whether is fully populated because of below error.

```
[ERROR] [23:02:19.082] Unable to create symbol table for : /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Build-media-api/workspace/src/main/java/com/sample/la/ms/controller/MediaController.java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve type parameter: S in class Resources
```

Q2)How can i a incprporate a angular js project with Jenkins Sonar Qube plugin. When i click on the "post build action" of my web project jenkins job, I get the SonarQube section with advance button. But that advance button only support maven configaration which my web(angular) project has a bower.json file use with grunt.

Comment: Is the screenshot above from *your* system? Because the Advanced Button appears under the SonarQube section, and you've posted a picture of the SonarQube runner section? What does your SonarQube section look like?

Comment: ah yes. I cant see the SonarQube section under Manage Jenkins->Configure System Know. Why is that happen Please?

Comment: The plugin SonarQube 2.2.1 also installed successfully.

Comment: You can see "SonarQube Plugin" under Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Installed tab?

Comment: yes i can see it. Also i dont think i have to restart jenkins server or anything right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add a SonarQube installation? If you haven't added an installation (step 2) you can't configure it.

Edit:
You're mixing two different things...
Your referenced link has two sections:

1. Adding SonarQube Server - 3 steps - on step 2 you have the "advanced" button
2. Adding SonarQube Runner - 2 steps - there is no "advanced" button on step 2

The advanced button only shows up for configuring the **SonarQube installation (server)**. If you have multiple installation of SonarQube you can add all of them (configure the details like URL etc.) and select one later in the jenkins build job.

Comment: yes sonar qube installation is done. Then under jenkis configure system, i can see the SonarQube Runner section. Then i add a SonarQube Runner. Then i enter a name and go with default settings which has the "Install automatically" check box clicked with install from Maven Central.Then I saved. Thats it. Am i missing any installation step here? So i assume jenkins will install the Sonar Qube runner for me and once i come back i dont see the advance button which is in step 2 for me to configure sonar runner.

Comment: So have you tried to use the SonarQube in one of your Project Configurations?  If it is installed you should see a new option for Sonar Qube after it is installed when you create a new configuration for your project.

Comment: @Johannes Zink   Thanks. I have two questions please. Can you check my edit answer

Answer (score 0):

When you say you don't see the advanced button there, where is "there"?

The configuration they are speaking of is actually when you are configuring your new project you are trying to build and deploy.  So obviously you have some web project that you wish to manage with Jenkins.  When you are configuring this new build process with Jenkins you should NOW see a new section for SonarQube.

Comment: yes i can see the new section for sonar qube under jenkins configaration. The problem is in the link i share on step 2, you can see the advance button above the red Delete SonarQube button. But in my case i am missing that advance button